# Is there a way to know whether NSURL points to a remote server or to an assets library on a user's device?

Tags: ios, nsurl

I have a data abstraction, which uses NSURL pointing to a video asset, which is either located locally on the device, or on a remote server.

How can I universally know, if it's a remote server asset or a local one? (I am fetching preview image for it, with 2 different methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSURL has a `-scheme` method, which returns an NSString.

Using this, you can check for 'http' or 'file' scheme using string comparison.

There is also the `-isFileReferenceURL` method which will tell you if it is a file reference or not.

[EDIT] as rmaddy points out in the comments, you should probably check for 'assets-library' scheme too.

Comment: Keep in mind that the URL will probably not have a `file` scheme for a local asset depending on how it was obtained. It will likely have an `asset-library` scheme.

Comment: Oops - typo. It's `assets-library`, not `asset-library`.

Comment: For me, only `if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"assets-library"])` is appropriate